# How did Sherlock find out who is the guilty one in "The Six Thatchers"?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

At the end of "The Six Thatchers" (Season 4 episode 1) Sherlock is on the bridge and deduced that

> The “English woman” is Mrs. Norberry, the secretary.

How did he come to this conclusion? I see absolutely no real clue or evidence that leads to her!

During the scene, Sherlock sees a few scenes in his head:

- The A.G.R.A. burglar saying: “You think you understand? You understand nothing.”
- Images of the Thatchers breaking
- His brother saying "code names Antarctica, Langdale, Porlock and Love"
- Mary talking about how receptionists know everything, hear everything

It seems to me that it's just a guess like "Hey, Mary told me about a receptionist earlier, this woman has a secretary, it must be her". That would be disappointing for Sherlock, so I hope there is another reason.

Comment: Between the accusation of Love and the accusation of its secretary, he witnesses Love's interrogation. I think that's where he understood it wasn't her. Then remember the thing about secretary, and since the secretary may be the one passing the orders at the end point...

Answer (score 5):

Amo means love, thus leading to lady Smallwood,its her code name as we see in the begining. That's why her card was disabled, but if not her, then maybe her secretary, who does all the actual work, Smallwood propably just gives commands.

Answer (score 1):

There are no clues. She is a woman, that's about it. In fact, when Sherlock approached her, if the secretary denied everything, there was no way Sherlock, or anybody else, could prove her involvement.

Yeah, it was a terribly written episode.